# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5pyViewer'

Tags: python, h5py

I have a question regarding h5pyViewer to view h5 files. I tried `pip install h5pyViewer` but that didn't work. I checked on Google and it states that `h5pyViewer` does not work for older versions of Python, but that there are a few solutions on GitHub. I downloaded this with `pip install git+https://github.com/Eothred/h5pyViewer.git` which finally gave me a successful installation.

Yet, when I want to import the package with `import h5pyViewer` it gave me the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5pyViewer'`. However when I tried to install it again it says:

```py
Requirement already satisfied: h5pyviewer in c:\users\celin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (-v0.0.1.15)Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Any ideas how to get out of this loop or in what other way I could access an `.h5` file?

Comment: What python version are you on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be so many things wrong so it's hard to say what the problem is.

1. The actual package import has a lowercase "v": `h5pyviewer` (as seen in your error message).
2. Your IDE/python runner may not be using your `Conda` environment (you can select the environment in `VSCode`, and if you are running a script in the terminal make sure your `Conda` env is enabled in that terminal)
3. The GitHub package might be exported from somewhere else.  Try something like `from Eothred import h5pyviewer`.
4. Maybe `h5pyviewer` is not even supposed to be imported this way!

Overall, I don't suggest using this package, it seems like it's broken on Python 3 and not well maintained. The code in GitHub looks sketchy, and very few people use it. A good indicator is usually the number of people that star or use the package, which seems extremely low. Additionally, it doesn't even have a real readme file! It doesn't say how to use it at all. Suggest you try something else like `pandas`. But if you really want to go with this, you can try the above debugging steps.

Comment: Thanks! I will try these steps out when im back at my computer. Can .h5 files be opened with panda as well?

Comment: with pandas you can inspect the data inside the hdf file through python and print statements, which is usually what you need to do with them :)

Comment: If you want a GUI application to view the contents of a HDF5 file, I suggest **HDFView** from **The HDF Group** (developers of HDF5). It is Java based, works great, and is constantly updated. ViTables and HDF Compass are 2 Python based browsers. I have also used all 3, and prefer HDF View (because of the updates). If you want to access a HDF5 file from a Python program, the most frequently used packages are h5py, pytables (aka tables) and pandas.